# How to get text position textarea input and div(contenteditable="true") like grammary

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, underline

For example, In this text, I want to get information about the position of the word ‘nme’ in the whole text (left / top).

I need support textarea / input/div (contenteditable="true").

I want to get word position in text like Grammarly.

**The screenshot was made by Grammarly and I wanted to implement such a function and they calculated the top:15px / left:27.8828px of the 'nme'**

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, maybe... this answer will give you an idea.

First, you need to get the the **style** of tag using [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_cssstyledeclaration.asp).

Then, pass it's value in an editable tag(*textarea*) so you are able to get and change it.

If this couldn't answer the question, i'm still hoping that it will give you an idea. :)

```js
function get() {
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var x = element.style.cssText;
  output.value = x;
}
function change() {
  var element = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var x = element.style = output.value;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color: red; top: 15px; left:27.8828px; width:31.5156px; height:22.5px;">nme</h1>
<button onclick="get()">Get the style</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="change()">Change the style</button>
```

Comment: Thank you . but My requirement is that I need to know the absolute position of the word in the textarea。

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't help. But as of now, I dont still quite understand what you want to do here. Please edit your question and clarify it. It could be helpful if you add sample/draft/image of the output you want to achieve.